# Even if the button ['state']=DISABLED, it activates the <Button-1> and <ButtonRelease-1> command functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I made myself a program in which I have multiple buttons and I need that buttons to send me a command when they are released.

```
self.predefined_1_button=Button(self.Background_Main, text="Predefined 1", width=10, heigh=2)
self.predefined_1_button.place(anchor='nw', x=10,y=100)
self.predefined_1_button['state']=DISABLED
self.predefined_1_button.bind('<Button-1>',self.function1)
self.predefined_1_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.function2)
```

At the start of the program the default state of the button is DISABLED (grayed out) and if I click on it the function1 and function2 are activating.

Do you have any ideeas or workarounds?

Comment: Setting the state to DISABLED only affects the visual highlighting and the calling of the function specified by the `command=` option (which is the normal way to react to a button being clicked).  Bindings added directly to the widget don't care about the state.  Perhaps you could add code to your two functions that checks the state, and returns immediately if DISABLED.

Comment: Oh yeah haha. Gosh I am so dumb. Thank you for the ideea :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is managed properly when calling the function assigned to the `command` attribute. If you bypass the `command` attribute and add your own bindings, it is up to you to check the state of the widget.

You will need to modify `self.function1` and `self.function2` to check the state, and only do their function if the state is normal.

```
def self.function1(self, event):
    if event.widget.cget("state") == "disabled":
        return
    ...
```