# I change button`s states to "disabled" but it works anyway

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making the TieTacToe game, and when we press a button, we don't need to press it again next time. To do this, I added an event to all of the buttons and changed the state of the pressed buttons to disabled, and its command to None but it still works. And when we press the button, it will change his size. But I need to keep it in the previous size

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

table = [
    [None, None, None],
    [None, None, None],
    [None, None, None]
]

turn = "red"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TieTacToe")
root.geometry("402x450")

def callback(event):
    global turn
    b = event.widget

    if turn == "red":
        b["bg"] = "red"
        table[int(b['text'].split("x")[0])][int(b['text'].split("x")[1])] = 1
        turn = "blue"
        b["text"] = "X"
        b["font"] = 6
        b["state"] = 'disabled'
        b["command"] = None
    else:
        b["bg"] = "blue"
        table[int(b['text'].split("x")[0])][int(b['text'].split("x")[1])] = 0
        turn = "red"
        b["text"] = "O"
        b["font"] = 6
        b["state"] = 'disabled'
        b["command"] = None
    print(table)

# table[0][0]
b1 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='0x0')
b1.place(x=85, y=100)
b1.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[0][1]
b2 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='0x1')
b2.place(x=170, y=100)
b2.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[0][2]
b3 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='0x2')
b3.place(x=255, y=100)
b3.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[1][0]
b4 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='1x0')
b4.place(x=85, y=200)
b4.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[1][1]
b5 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='1x1')
b5.place(x=170, y=200)
b5.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[1][2]
b6 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='1x2')
b6.place(x=255, y=200)
b6.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[2][0]
b7 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='2x0')
b7.place(x=85, y=300)
b7.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[2][1]
b8 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='2x1')
b8.place(x=170, y=300)
b8.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

# table[2][2]
b9 = tk.Button(root, padx=20, pady=20, bg='gray', fg='gray', text='2x2')
b9.place(x=255, y=300)
b9.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [even-if-the-button-state-disabled-it-activates-the-button-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of you problem is you have used `.bind()` to those buttons.`callback` function will be called *when left click on those buttons* instead of *when you press on those buttons*.

The process:
`left click  =>  the button is clicked.`

You could use `.unbind()`.Like:

```
def callback(event):
    global turn
    b = event.widget
    if turn == "red":
        table[int(b['text'].split("x")[0])][int(b['text'].split("x")[1])] = 1
        b["bg"] = "blue"
        turn = "blue"
        b["text"] = "X"
        b["font"] = 6
        b["state"] = 'disabled' # Actually, if you want to make you button clickable, you could just remove the line.
        b.unbind("<Button-1>") # just do unbind 
    else:
        table[int(b['text'].split("x")[0])][int(b['text'].split("x")[1])] = 0
        b["bg"] = "red"
        turn = "red"
        b["text"] = "O"
        b["font"] = 6
        b["state"] = 'disabled'
        b.unbind("<Button-1>")
```